# Does json.Unmarshal maintain order of JSON arrays

Tags: arrays, json, go, unmarshalling

Does `json.Unmarshal` preserve the order of JSON arrays passed in?

I know that in JSON itself, arrays are not to be expected to maintain order. However, given 2 calls of `json.Unmarshal` with an identical set of data, can I guarantee that the order of the go slices into which the arrays are being unmarshalled, will have the same order?

Comment: JSON arrays are ordered as described in the [RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#section-1).   Perhaps you are thinking of JSON objects, which are unordered.

Comment: That's right, I was thinking about fields in an object

Comment: "I know that in JSON itself, arrays are not to be expected to maintain order." -- This is absolutely not true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, ordering is the fundamental property of [array data structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure), so go implicitly maintains it when un/marshaling slices and arrays to and from JSON.

Note however that [Associative arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array), called "Objects" in JSON and ["Map types" in go](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Map_types) (or simply "maps"), are "an unordered group of elements", so un/marshaling them to and from JSON does *not* preserve the order of the key/value pairs.

Finally, marshaling a struct into a JSON object (aka an associative array) does maintain the order of keys based on the order of struct fields, per [`json.Marshal(...)`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal).